# Parse HTML table with HTML DOM to array

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to get a HTML table into an array with php. I already found a post with a code but if I'm using that code it will display not correct this Table (Second row/Dinsdag):

http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/16/s/s00156.htm
Output:

```
Array
(
    [  Dinsdag     ] => 1
    [] => 1
    [  Veh.       ec4       276.     ] => 1
    [  Vec.       nsk1_       202.     ] => 1
    [  Vog       rkt       112.     ] => 1
    [  Sle       ma       173.     ] => 1
    [  Rem       wi       275.     ] => 1
    [  Wie       ne       172.     ] => 1
    [  Klo       en       276.     ] => 1
)
```

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

    $table = array();

    $html = file_get_html('http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/16/s/s00156.htm');
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
      $first = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
      $sec = $row->find('tr',2)->plaintext;

      $table[$sec] = true;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($table);
    echo '</pre>';
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you check this is not right?!

http://prntscr.com/6r5unj

Can i get the output like this?

```
null
null
Veh. ec4 276.
Veh. ec4 276.
Vog rkt 112.
Sle ma  173.
Rem wi  275.
Wie ne  172.
Klo en  276.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>TEST page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/16/s/s00156.htm');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
  $first = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
  $sec = $row->find('tr',2)->plaintext.'<br>';

  $table[$sec] = true;
}

echo '<pre>';
echo $table;
echo '</pre>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```